# How to reload packages using shortcut?

Tags: front-end

When developing packages I need to `Get` my packages repeatedly, and it will be convenient to set a shortcut to reload the packages.

Suppose the structure of the notebook is like:

**First cell**

```
PacletDataRebuild[]
Get["Notation`"]
MemoryInUse[]
```

**Lots of cells in several pages**

```
Print/@Range@20
```

**The cell I'm working with**

```
foo[1]
```

**Other cells**

```
foo1[1]
```

### What I want

I want to evaluate the first cell using a shortcut, **without changing the current selection of the notebook**. Is there convenient way to achieve this?

### What I tried

I tried two methods by modifying `KeyEventTranslations.tr` but failed

#### Method 1

```
    Item[KeyEvent["t", Modifiers -> {Command}],
        FrontEndExecute[
            FrontEnd`SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],Before,Notebook]
        ];
        FrontEndExecute[
            FrontEnd`SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],Next,Cell]
        ];
        FrontEndExecute[
            FrontEnd`SelectionEvaluate[EvaluationNotebook[]]
        ]
    ]
```

Firstly these codes just don't work, and secondly they change the position of current selection.

#### Method 2

```
    Item[KeyEvent["t", Modifiers -> {Command}],
        KernelExecute[
            Get["Notation`"]
        ]
    ]
```

I found the undocumented function `KernelExecute` in other questions, but don't know how to use it.

Comment: You can make the top cells an initialization cell and then use Evaluation -> Evaluate Initialization Cells.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thx! but I use `code` as the default input cell style, and the `code` cells are initialization cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a `DockedCell` with a `Button`?

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], DockedCells -> Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[
     Button["<<Notation`", (<< "Notation`";)]]]
   ]]
```

Comment: Thx! It's more flexible than modifying `MenuSetup.tr`. Is there a shortcut to evaluate the `DockedCell `?

Comment: @lilyric Not that I know of, but I'm far from an expert on such tricks.

Answer (score 2):

After trial and error I find the following method:

```
    Menu["Others", 
    {
        MenuItem["Reload xx`",
            FrontEnd`KernelExecute[
                Get["xx.wl",Path->FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory,"Applications"}]]//Timing//First//Print;
            ],
            MenuKey["t", Modifiers -> {Command}],
            MenuEvaluator -> Automatic, Method -> "Queued"
        ],
    }]
```

add these lines into `MenuSetup.tr`. The context `` FrontEnd` ``  and the options `MenuEvaluator -> Automatic, Method -> "Queued"` are necessary.

It has one drawback left. After reloading the package `xx.wl`, the symbols in `xx.wl` will not be auto-completed unless evaluating something.

Comment: BTW, you can write ```FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands``` to `init.m` instead of modifying front-end files.

Comment: @rnotlnglgq Thx! I'll try it later.